# Normal mapping, confusion on space

Tags: opengl, glsl, normals

Up to now, the only normal mapping I encountered was with maps already in world space so I just extracted the info from the texture and transformed them with the normal matrix.

Now I wanted to try to use a normal map that is in tangent space, but I immediately became really confused.

What I've in my code up-to-now is

**Vertex Shader**

```
 ...
passedPosition = modelViewMatrix*vec4(vertexPosition,1.0);
 ...
```

**Fragment Shader**

```
 vec3 V = normalize(-passedPosition .xyz);   // Eye vector
 ...
 vec3 L_dir = passedPosition .xyz - lights[i].lightPosition.xyz;
 vec3 L = normalize(L_dir); 
 ...
```

And then proceed with my lighting calculations.

All the tutorial I came across change all the light directions and the view vector into tangent space (in the vertex shared) and then extract the normal from the texture and keep going (in fragment). 
My issue here is that I'd like to avoid to access all my lights information in the vertex shared, so my questions are:

- Does make sense to pass to the fragment shared the t,b,n vectors so that I transform the light directions there? Should I consider access all my lighting information in vertex shared (I have an array of Light struck which has more than just the position) and then passed them on to the fragment shared? Is something I'd like to avoid, but if is much better I can think of it.
- There is a way to perform normal mapping that is  more compatible with what I've now (snippets above posted).
- Should I consider change my calculations from view space to world space? In that case, how can I perform normal mapping?

Comment: Why do you not want to compute your light vectors per-vertex? Is this for deferred shading or something? Doing this in the fragment shader will be slower than transforming your vectors into tangent-space in the vertex shader.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Mainly because my fragment shaders are mainly generated on the fly whilst my vertex shader is somewhat fixed. For the lighting system I have with the lighting info I also have something that must be generated. This is nothing that I can't change, but it won't be as easy as changing the shaders code. Is therefore going to tangent-space (computing both Eye and Light vector in vertex-shader) the best option?

Comment: It is not necessary, it is just usually the way things are done unless you are using deferred shading. Operations computed per-vertex happen much less frequently than per-fragment, so most of the time the idea is to move any calculations that can be interpolated per-fragment into the vertex shader. There is no reason you cannot sample your tangent-space normal map in the fragment shader and then transform it into world- or view-space, it will just be a little extra work. And it will also involve the inverse TBN matrix (tangent-space -> object-space) instead of (object-space -> tangent-space).